# Better way to update layout in cytoscape.js for performance

Tags: cytoscape.js

Been trying to achieve "realtime" update in my graph using cytoscape.js. When new data arrives, I add it to the graph using `cy.add(elements)` and running the layout, expecting the new data and the existing one would be placed based on the layout-algorithm(FYI, I'm using dagre extension).

The problem is the layout-update takes over 100ms with 100 nodes, which is not good and when the graph gets bigger and complicated, I can see the frame-drop.

So I wonder if there's any better way to update the layout when new elements should be added. I thought I could simply locate the newly added nodes manually without running the layout but that would require me to understand the algorithm well which might take more resource.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [cytoscape-layout-utilities](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-layout-utilities) extension to properly place the new nodes closer to their existing neighbours (see `instance.placeNewNodes(nodesWithoutLayout` function in its API). You can then apply an incremental layout which starts from the current node positions instead of calculating the layout from scratch. There is an example of this process in its [demo](https://ivis-at-bilkent.github.io/cytoscape.js-layout-utilities/demo.html) where you can add random neighbors to the selected nodes and then it applies an incremental layout immediately (see 'Add random neighbors to selected' button).